# Hide/Display Background Text on Hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I can't figure out how to change the background to display only text "Members Only"on hover without all the other elements. I have this box element with content:

```
<div class="box-locked"><div class="members-only">Members Only</div><div class="heading-non-members"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></div>Getting Started</a>
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Your question title is diffrent from your actually question. You want to change the div with the class `members-only` but when? What have you tried yet?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand it well, but I think you want something like this:

```
<a><div class="box-locked"><div class="members-only">Members Only</div><div class="heading-non-members"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></div><span>Getting Started</span></a>
```

Added `span` wrapping the text. And this is the css:

```
a .members-only {
    display: none
}

a span {
    display: inline
}

a:hover .members-only {
    display: inline
}

a:hover span {
    display: none
}
```

See it working on the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MH3Dc/

But be aware that the link will still work! Anyway, didn't realize where the *image* (discribed on title) come into play.

Comment: Hi, I'm impressed by the fast answer. I'm sorry I haven't mentioned that the i class "fa fa-home" is an icon and it still displaying after hover.